# How functional is World Sim, GoSIM and other "International" Data SIMs, in terms of coverage, quality of service and cost?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans

I am contemplating if it is worth investing in international data SIMs (such as [World Sim](https://www.worldsim.com/data-sim-card/) or [GoSIM](http://www.gosim.com/data-sim-card.html)) when travelling around several countries.

In particular I am interested in:

- how good the coverage is,
- how easy to activate and use they are,
- how good the quality of service is,
- and how much they cost

Comment: Getting a visitor sim card from the airport once you arrive is usually much cheaper than this, especially when it comes to data.

Comment: Depends on your requirements for a "good choice". Coverage? Ease of use? Price?

Comment: About everything, a review.

Comment: @MaxFerreira The way you phrased the question renders it opinion-based, and is hence attracting a fair amount of close votes. I modified the title and question content to render it more answerable.

Comment: still asking others to do the research and draw a conclusion. Better to ask the subquestions since they're factual.

Comment: IMO this is an excellent question that needs to be kept open.

Comment: It's not "opinion-based" it's fact based. I'm not asking what's better in a user opinion, I'm asking what's the correct option for this situation since I explained all my context.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Piranha Mobile SIM. The coverage is as good as it gets since it uses local networks, activation was easy, expect quite a few phone reboots, using it is very easy... The situation it solves and it solves very well is the following: you arrive to an airport. You need transportation to your accomodation and it's arranged but there's some problem. Maybe you need to call the hotel from the curb outside or call the driver, maybe you are on public transit and want a quick peek at the local transport company website or Google Maps. Grabbing a local SIM on landing is not always feasible nor is it economical always (for example at Gatwick they will charge you a very hefty surchage for buying the SIM at the airport) or perhaps you are just transiting through and leave the country the next day. For the few minutes / kilobytes this takes vs the amount of stress it resolves it's an excellent deal.

If I am in a country for a few days I will grab a SIM once downtown, sure. But the above situation have occurred to me quite a few times before I got a Piranha SIM.

Comment: Looks like it's more or less 0.10EUR per MB. Where did you used the PIRANHA MOBILE (which countries)?

Comment: USA, UK, Austria, Hungary. And yes the cost is high but again the use case requires very little usage.